# Make result in tryCatch expr available to warning handler

Tags: r, error-handling

In the usual implementation of `tryCatch`, the warning handler usually returns some custom value, e.g.

```
tryCatch(expr,
  warning = function(w) { print(w) ; return(NULL) }
```

What if I want the warning handler to return the result of `expr` without running `expr` again? (The reason is that `expr` is an API call that cuts into my limit.) I tried

```
tryCatch({res <- expr; return(res)},
      warning = function(w) { print(w) ; return(res) }
```

but of course this doesn't work because `res` is not available in the `warning` handler.

Comment: check my [tryCatch2](https://github.com/jangorecki/logR/blob/37a52bd52abe8f784f4d94dd6841bdc5cb7aa5d1/R/logR.R#L21) function which uses `withCallingHandlers` and `tryCatch` to achieve what you need.